# mocha unit-test return axios undefined

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, axios

Page loads and work perfectly, however when trying to run unit test i get `axios is not defined`.

Here's what my code looks like.

library is located on the index of the application e.g:

```
<html>
 <body> ... </body>
 ...
 <script src="/lib/axios.js">
</html>
```

on my list.js file i ref. axios as:

```
const { get } = axios
...
class List extends Component { ... }
export default List;
```

on my test code i ref. the react module as:

```
import List = '../../list';
describe('load list', () => {
...
}
```

when i run the test i get: `axios is not defined`

How can i make axios to be defined while running unit-test?

Comment: Your tests aren't loading the DOM, meaning your script tag in HTML isn't being engaged. Try just importing axios into your test. Moreover, your unit tests should NOT be making HTTP calls anyway; these are integration tests. At most, you want to stub/mock out these calls.

Comment: yeah! -  that was it, thx a lot!

Comment: Nice! It's an extremely common issue to have to deal with, insofar as you'll find libraries out there like Jsdom that help mimic the DOM during tests. Good luck!